# How to customize CMFCVisualManager's colors?

Tags: colors, appearance

There are some COLORREF member variables in CMFCVisualManager's, and more ones in drived classes, but when I drive my class from CMFCVisualManager and change values of the variables in constructor, does not anything change?!

Please help me
best regards,

Comment: Can you please share at least part of your code and describe what you have tried so far?